# Creating a button in xml in android

Tags: android, button

[image]
I am able to use this image for button by making it 9 patch.But my concern is that could we make such a button using xml in android.

Comment: <Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:background="@drawable/image" />

Comment: @KMI : please read the question clear-fully.thanks for reply

Comment: sorry man!! i m not getting it .can u explain it little more clearly

Comment: Just out of curiosity: why would you *not* want to use the 9-patch?

Comment: @KMI : i want to use xml to create such a button not a image itself.

Comment: @ShabbirPanjesha:: similar to this http://android-vogue.blogspot.in/2011/05/android-button-design-and-selector.html

Comment: @MH : so that i would become independent of all densities and all resolutions and i wont have to worry about creating 9 patch for xhdpi,hdpi,ldpi,mdpi

Comment: @ShabbirPanjesha: Okay, I see how you might want to avoid that. As far as I know, what you're after is *not* possible through xml (as hotveryspicy already pointed out), but you can probably create a very close approximation programmatically. That being said, it'll definitely take you longer to work out such a solution than creating a couple of 9-patches for the different dpi buckets.

Answer (score 0):

I did my button using xml, but this is just a regular button but not exactly the one you posted with a pointed arrow. But you may use this as a start?

```
<!-- Bottom 1dp Shadow -->
<item>
    <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
        <solid android:color="#383838" />

        <corners android:radius="5dp" />
    </shape>
</item>

<!-- Green Top color -->
<item android:bottom="1dp" android:top="2dp">
    <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
        <gradient
            android:angle="270"
            android:endColor="#2F361D"
            android:startColor="#67724B" />

        <corners android:radius="5dp" />
    </shape>
</item>
```